# How to remove dot from multiple folders

Tags: command-line, 18.04, files, filesystem

I have several folders that i want to hide. In my case just by appending a dot at the start of the folder name serves the purpose.

In case of single folder i can just use the command

```
mv folder .folder
```

and vice versa.
But if i have several folders like f1, f2 ,f3. How can i append dot to all the folders and also later remove all dots?

Comment: You've not said what folder names you want to rename, but you could use a `find` command with `-exec` option that executes a `mv` for the found file/folder... but that's only one option.

Comment: Maybe this link could help you a little: https://techsphinx.com/linux/rename-directories-in-linux/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `rename` command to match the beginning of the file name and then substitute it by a dot. As in the example below, you can add the `-n` option for dry run while tweaking you regular expression and/or the file match expression. Here is an example.

```bash
rename 's/^/./' f* -n
```

```
rename(f1, .f1)
rename(f2, .f2)
rename(f3, .f3)
```

Keep in mind the dot `.` have a meaning of any character when it is used in the left side (which is regular expression) and it must be escaped by a backslash when we need to match literal dot. So to do the reverse rename the correct command should be:

```bash
rename 's/^\.//' .f* -n
```

Note you need to remove the `-n` option to perform the actual renaming.

Comment: https://imgur.com/rmKG4XX   It shows similar output but folder name remains same

Comment: Hi, @mahfujasif, you need to remove the option `-n` in order to apply the actual changes.

Comment: Sorry i missed that, yes it works now

Comment: @mahfujasif, you are welcome! I forgot to mention that the dot `.` have a meaning of any character when it is used in the left side (which is regexp) and in this case must be escaped by a backslash, so to do the reverse rename the correct command should be `rename 's/^\.//' .f*`.